# Unsure where to put subscription for 3 observables chained with switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

```
this._authService.loggedInUser$.pipe(switchMap((loggedInUser: LoggedInUser) => {
      return this._userSerialService.getUserSerial().pipe(switchMap(serial => {
          return this._usersService.getCurrentUser().pipe(switchMap(currentUser => [loggedInUser, currentUser, serial]));
        }),
      );
    })).subscribe(([loggedInUser, currentUser, serial]) => {

    });
```

The above code attempts to chain 3 observables together and map their results to an array using switchMaps. I need the result values for all three observables in my final subscription. However when I attempt to subscribe in the way shown above I'm given a compiler error that says `Type 'LoggedInUser' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

If I do `subscribe(res => {}`, then res ends up being only the value of loggedInUser, not all three values.

What do I need to change in my code to make sure that I have access to all three values in my subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like switchMap is what you need.  switchMap is used to "switch" a source observable under the hood so that a new observable can emit into the stream.  It handles unsubscribing from the prior source and subscribing to the new one.

In your case, you can simply use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest).  This will emit an array of all 3 values once all of the source observables have emitted a value and it will continue to emit whenever any of them receive a new value.

```
authUser$ = this._authService.loggedInUser$;
serial$   = this._userSerialService.getUserSerial();
user$     = this._usersService.getCurrentUser();

data$ = combineLatest([authUser$, serial$, user$]);


data$.subscribe(([loggedInUser, serial, currentUser]) => {
    ...
});
```

It can be handy to map the values to an object, so they are easy to retrieve in your template like:

```
data$ = combineLatest([authUser$, serial$, user$]).pipe(
    map(([authUser, serial, user]) => ({authUser, serial, user}))
);
```

It's also handy if you leverage the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your template rather than subscribing in your component.

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <ul>
        <li>Current User: {{ data.user }}</li>
        <li>Logged in User: {{ data.authUser }}</li>
        <li>User Serial: {{ data.serial }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`switchMap` operator takes a function which returns an `Observable`, then subscribe to it.
The problem here is that your last `switchMap` gets an array instead of an `Observable`.
You can use `map` instead to transform the data.

```
this._authService.loggedInUser$.pipe(
  switchMap(loggedInUser => this._userSerialService.getUserSerial().pipe(
    switchMap(serial => this._usersService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
      map(currentUser => [loggedInUser, currentUser, serial]))
    )
  ))
).subscribe(([loggedInUser, currentUser, serial]) => {
  ...
});
```